# Delete files on HDFS via shell where filename contains number inferior to given value

Tags: shell, hdfs

I have searched other existing questions but without success.

At the end of a spark job, I need to do some cleaning via sh scripts.
The goal is to delete any files containing in their name, a number inferior to a given value.

For example, let's consider this HDFS folder structure

```
myDirectory
  myFile_20210315.csv
  myFile_20210316.csv
  myFile_20210317.csv
```

I would like to start the SH script with the argument 20210316, and that it deletes only myFile_20210315.csv.

So far I have this commands that is able to isolate the number part of the file, but I can't figure out the next step :

```
hdfs dfs -ls myDirectory/myFile*.csv | awk '{print $8}' | sed -e s/[^0-9]//g
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ended up finding the solution. Below is the script.

I call the script doing ./myScript.sh 20210315

```
for f in `hdfs dfs -ls myDirectory/*.csv | awk '{print $8}'`;
do
  echo Processing $f
  fileNumberValue=`hdfs dfs -ls $f | awk '{print $8}' | sed -e s/[^0-9]//g`
  if [ $fileNumberValue -lt "$1" ]; then
    echo $fileNumberValue inferior to "$1" : deleting $f on HDFS
    hdfs dfs -rm $f
  fi
done
```